# Python Parse XML using xml.dom.minidom - Extract Items within List

Tags: python, xml, dom, xml-parsing, parsexml

I have lengthy xml this actually ebay listings using ebay api, I am trying to extract following structure in that xml dom:

I am only putting the segment that I am having trouble with, please let me know if you need to see the entire file, I could upload it to a location or do an attachment as a picture.

```
<ItemSpecifics>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Room</Name>
<Value>Living Room</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Type</Name>
<Value>Sofa Set</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>...</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Upholstery Fabric</Name>
<Value>Microfiber</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Color</Name>
<Value>Beiges</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Style</Name>
<Value>Contemporary</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>MPN</Name>
<Value>F7615, F7616, F7617, F7618, F7619, F7620</Value>
</NameValueList>
</ItemSpecifics>
```

Here is dom structure for another ebay item:

```
ItemSpecifics>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Brand</Name>
<Value>Nikon</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Model</Name>
<Value>D3100</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>MPN</Name>
<Value>9798</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Type</Name>
<Value>Digital SLR</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Megapixels</Name>
<Value>14.2 MP</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Optical Zoom</Name>
<Value>3.1x</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Screen Size</Name>
<Value>3"</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Color</Name>
<Value>Black</Value>
</NameValueList>
</ItemSpecifics>
```

But when I tried to extract above elements I endup getting following error:

```
   attID=att.attributes.getNamedItem('Name').nodeValue
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodeValue'
```

this is what I get right after I parse response:

```
[<DOM Element: NameValueList at 0x103398878>, <DOM Element: NameValueList at 0x103398ab8>, <DOM Element: NameValueList at 0x103398cf8>, <DOM Element: NameValueList at 0x103398f38>, <DOM Element: NameValueList at 0x1033b31b8>, <DOM Element: NameValueList at 0x1033b33f8>, <DOM Element: NameValueList at 0x1033b3638>, <DOM Element: NameValueList at 0x1033b3878>]
```

And this is what I get inside my for loop before getting the error:

```
<DOM Element: NameValueList at 0x103398878>
```

Here is my code:

```
  results = {}
  attributeSet=response.getElementsByTagName('NameValueList')
  print attributeSet
  attributes={}
  for att in attributeSet:
    print att
    attID=att.attributes.getNamedItem('Name').nodeValue
    attValue=getSingleValue(att,'Value')
    attributes[attID]=attValue
  result['attributes']=attributes
  return result
```

This is my xml request method:

```
def sendRequest(apicall,xmlparameters):
  connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(serverUrl)
  connection.request("POST", '/ws/api.dll', xmlparameters, getHeaders(apicall))
  response = connection.getresponse()
  if response.status != 200:
    print "Error sending request:" + response.reason
  else: 
    data = response.read()
    connection.close()
  return data
```

Comment: Is `<NameValueList>...</NameValueList>` actually in your dataset?

Comment: yeah the xml dom i have put in the question is actually what get printed out

Comment: That's interesting. I thought maybe you truncated to but it seemed like a strange place to do so.

Comment: so I tried a different item and updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attributes.getNamedItem()` gives you the attributes of an element, not it's children, and a `<NameValueList>` element has no `Name` attribute, only `<Name>` elements. You'd have to loop over the contained elements of `<NameValueList>`, or use `.getElementsByTagName('Name')` and `.getElementsByTagName('Value')` to get individual sub-nodes.

Do yourself a big favour though and use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead; that API is far pythononic and easier to use than the XML DOM API:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

etree = ET.fromstring(data)
results = {}
for nvl in etree.findall('NameValueList'):
    name = nvl.find('Name').text
    value = nvl.find('Value').text
    results[name] = value
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, of this document is not ItemSpecifics> so in that case how will I narrow down based on ElementTreeAPI

Comment: any chance you could provide a helpful snippet

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: updated; all `Name` and `Value` elements are used to create a `results` dictionary in that snippet.

Comment: so I can directly give the url xml response? every example i look is giving it with document instead of using a xml response

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: What *is* the XML response? Is it a urllib2 urlopen response?

Comment: and then I use data=sendRequest('GetItem',xml)
response=parseString(data)

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: `data` is a python string, so simply use the `.fromstring(data)` function from the ElementTree module.

Comment: interestingly it doesn't find any NaveValueList do you think its someting to do with parser and this is what etree spits out <Element '{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}GetItemResponse' at 0x101e3f5d0> this looks like a object instead of python string or am i wrong..?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: experiment with the code in a python prompt; download the URL locally, open it with the `open()` command, and load it into a elementtree, then play! Python makes that real easy.

Comment: see, using xml.dom.minidom's parseString i can parse the response to string so i did that and use that instead of data i am not sure what ElementTree is actually giving me back to even start the debug

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: that's what the link to the documentation is for :-) Use it, there are tutorials there!